# Different level of transparency for edgeline and fill in matplotlib or seaborn distribution plot

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to set different levels of transparency (= alpha) for the edge line and fill of a distribution plot that I created in matplotlib/seaborn. For example:

```
ax1 = sns.distplot(BSRDI_DF, label="BsrDI", bins=newBins, kde=False,
                  hist_kws={"edgecolor": (1,0,0,1), "color":(1,0,0,0.25)})
```

The above approach does not work, unfortunately. Does anybody have any idea how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** Nevermind, I thought using `color` instead of `facecolor` was causing the problem but it seems the output that I got only looked right because the patches were overlapping, giving seemingly darker edges.

After investigating the issue further, [it looks like seaborn is hard-setting the alpha level at 0.4](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/0beede57152ce80ce1d4ef5d0c0f1cb61d118375/seaborn/distributions.py#L213), which supersedes the arguments passed to `hist_kws=`

```
sns.distplot(x, kde=False, hist_kws={"edgecolor": (1,0,0,1), "lw":5, "facecolor":(0,1,0,0.1), "rwidth":0.8})
```

[image]

While using the same parameters to `plt.hist()` gives:

```
plt.hist(x, edgecolor=(1,0,0,1), lw=5, facecolor=(0,1,0,0.1), rwidth=0.8)
```

[image]

**Conclusion:** if you want different alpha levels for edges and face colors, you'll have to use matplotlib directly, and not seaborn.

Comment: This is exactly the code from the question. While the question is not clear about what exactly is not working, the solution cannot be to repost the code from the question.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Actually, it's not. The OP was using `edgecolor` and `color`, while the correct way to do it is time use `edgecolor` and `**face**color`. I guess I should have pointed out the difference in my answer

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Nevermind, my answer did not solve the problem after all

Comment: Agreed. Although I do offer a--somewhat unhelpful--suggestion on how to obtain the desired output.

Comment: The `hist_kw` could be given the `alpha`, something like `hist_kws={"edgecolor": (1,0,0,1), "color":"green", "alpha":0.1}`. Would that help?

Comment: I got it. You have to set `"alpha":None`.

Comment: Thank you! After a couple more hours of trying I also reached the conclusion that I need to use matplotlib directly.

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be that seaborn sets an alpha parameter for the histogram. While `alpha` defaults to `None` for a usual histogram, such that something like

```
plt.hist(x, lw=3, edgecolor=(1,0,0,0.75), color=(1,0,0,0.25))
```

works as expected, seaborn sets this alpha to some given value. This overwrites the alpha that is set in the RGBA tuples.

**The solution is to set alpha explicitely to `None`**:

```
ax = sns.distplot(x, kde=False, hist_kws={"lw":3, "edgecolor": (1,0,0,0.75),
                                                  "color":(1,0,0,0.25),"alpha":None})
```

A complete example:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randn(60)

ax = sns.distplot(x, label="BsrDI", bins=np.linspace(-3,3,10), kde=False, 
                  hist_kws={"lw":3, "edgecolor": (1,0,0,0.75), 
                                    "color":(1,0,0,0.25),"alpha":None})

plt.show()
```

[image]