# to_rgba in Seaborn stripplot - Set different transparency for filling color and edgecolor

Tags: seaborn, transparency

I want to set different transparencies for filling color and edgecolor in seaborn stripplot:

```
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.colors import to_rgba

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")


sns.stripplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker",
              data=tips,
              palette={'Yes': to_rgba('darkgreen', 0.3), 'No': to_rgba('red', 0.3)},
              edgecolor='black', linewidth=1,)
```

Why doesn't it work? I just want to keep black adgecolor (keep `black` as `alpha = 1.0`) but make the filling colors to be transparent (`darkgreen` and `red` to be `alpha = 0.3`). If I use `alpha`, it will make both to be transparent.

[image]

I can use  `scatterplot`  to achieve similar thing, but I hope I can use  `stripplot` :

```
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.colors import to_rgba

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

color_dict = {'Yes': to_rgba('darkgreen', 0.1),
              'No': to_rgba('red', 0.1)}

sns.scatterplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, hue = "smoker", palette=color_dict, edgecolor='black', linewidth=1)
```

The figure will be:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to set different alpha values based on smoke = Yes/No would to use the below code. You can set different colors and alpha as required.

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

ax=sns.stripplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips[tips.smoker == "Yes"], alpha = 0.3, color = 'darkgreen', edgecolor='black', linewidth=1) 
sns.stripplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips[tips.smoker == "No"], alpha = 0.3, color = 'red', edgecolor='black', linewidth=1)
```

**Plot**

[image]

**EDIT**

To set the colors directly, you can set your custom palette as below and then use `smoker` as hue.

```
# Create an array with the colors you want to use
colors = ["red", "darkgreen"]
# Set your custom color palette
sns.set_palette(sns.color_palette(colors))
#Use hue for smoker to differentiate colors
sns.stripplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, alpha = 0.3, hue = "smoker", edgecolor='black', linewidth=1)
```

IF your requirement is that HAVE to use `to_rgba()`, then you can set it in colors and keep the alpha here as well. This is the other code...

```
# Create an array with the colors you want to use
colors = [to_rgba("red", 0.3), to_rgba("darkgreen", 0.3)]
# Set your custom color palette
sns.set_palette(sns.color_palette(colors))
#Use hue for smoker to differentiate colors
sns.stripplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, hue = "smoker", edgecolor='black', linewidth=1)
```

In both cases, plot will be as below.

[image]

**New Requirement**

As you mentioned in the update, you are ok with the colors from scatter plot. You can write a small function to add jitter to your figure, which will achieve what you are looking for. See the update to your scatterplot code below to achieve what you are looking for.

```
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.colors import to_rgba
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
color_dict = {'Yes': to_rgba('darkgreen', 0.1), 'No': to_rgba('red', 0.1)}

#The days are strings, convert to numbers for plotting
Numday = {'Thur': 1, 'Fri': 2, 'Sat': 3, 'Sun' : 4}

def addJitter(x): ##Function to add jitter. Adjust numbers to make it thick/thin
    return x + random.uniform(0, .3) -.15

## Convert day -> Numday which is a different number for each day
tips['numDays'] = tips['day'].astype("string").apply(lambda x: numDays[x])
## Use jitter function to add jitter to each numDays
tips['jitter'] = tips['numDays'].apply(lambda x: addJitter(x))

sns.scatterplot(x= tips.jitter, y=tips.total_bill, hue = tips.smoker, palette=color_dict, edgecolor='black', linewidth=1)
## You will need to reset the x-axis to show the day
plt.xticks([1,2,3,4])
plt.gca().set_xticklabels(['Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Redox. Actually, I want to set `alpha = 0.3` for the green and red filling color, but keep the black edge color to be solid. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @Joe - I had the alphas at 0.3 and 0.6, now both are 0.3. The edgecolor is solid black above.  Is there something else/different you need?

Comment: Hi @Redox. Right now both the filling colours and the edge colour (black) are forced to be 0.3. Is it possible to highlight the black edge color (`alpha`=1.0), while setting the infill colours (red and green to `alpha =0.3`)? Much appreciated.

Comment: I didn't realize alpha for the line was 1. From the code [here](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/0beede57152ce80ce1d4ef5d0c0f1cb61d118375/seaborn/distributions.py#L213) and a previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46715409/different-level-of-transparency-for-edgeline-and-fill-in-matplotlib-or-seaborn-d) - second answer, looks like alpha for the line is hard set and can't be updated. So, I think this may not be possible. At least everything I tried (collection, set_edgecolor, etc.) all appear to be getting overridden by this

Comment: Hi @Redox, get it. Thanks so much for your help and time! Is it possible to modify the colours themselves as I did, adding alpha parameter to the colour values using `to_rgba`? I also tried to use multiple layers (one layer uses red and green colours with `alpha=0.3`, but no edge colour; the other layer uses white colour with black edge colour, `alpha=1.0`). Still not good.

Comment: Not sure if fully understand, but see the EDIT section. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi @Redox, Unfortunately, it can't achieve what I want. I edited my question also and used `scatterplot` to show what I want. But I really hope `stripplot` to get the same thing.

Comment: If you are ok with the colors in scatterplot, then check req2 updated which will get you what you want. With stipplot, unfortunately, the edgecolor will get reset. But, hope you have have the plot you are looking for. Hope this works for you